# Executing a PowerShell script with admin credentials

Tags: powershell

I've been asked to write a script that copies a file from one location to another that can be run by users. Code below (without specific names...of course)

```
Move-Item -Path Dir\text.txt -Destination Dir2\Text.txt

Get-ChildItem -path Dir2 Text.txt | Rename-Item -newname { $_.name -replace '.txt','.in'}

Move-Item -Path Dir2\*.in -Destination Dir3
```

I've created a shortcut so that they won't need to open up PowerShell and run it manually which works fine when ran using my admin account.  However, when they try and run the script nothing happens.

As I'm still learning PowerShell, it's safe to say that I'm stumped and have no idea how to move forward.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Give Modify rights to Dir1, Dir2, and Dir3 to the users who you want to run the script?

Comment: The various directories already have those rights and it still says that access is still denied.

Comment: The error message then is pretty clear that what is not configured correctly is access rights. Modify has all of the rights you need to do a move. Read/Write/Delete, you should double check those rights. That there is an ACE that includes the user and applies to all of the files or folders that you are trying to operate on. Without showing those settings, I'll be unable to help diagnose what's wrong, but the issue is undoubtedly with file permissions (or share permissions if to a remote UNC path),

Comment: @Monkeybum, For future reference, there's quite a difference between `nothing happens` and `says that access is still denied.`

Comment: Very true, I apologise for saying nothing happens. The first time i tested the script i was looking in the new directory for the file to be there are nothing arrived hence the statement 'nothing happens'.  
I shall look into the file permissions and share permissions and see if I can see the issue.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Locked files can occasionally cause an access denied error as well.